# dispatch_async doesn't go into loop

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch

I need  to fill in array. I have two methods. First of this create object that need to be added to array. I do it like this:

```
 __block NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:inputArray.count];
    dispatch_queue_t queue =dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);


dispatch_sync(queue, ^{

        dispatch_apply(inputArray.count,queue , ^(size_t index) {
            [array insertObject:[self getObject:[inputArray objectAtIndex:index]] atIndex:index];                      

        });
    });
```

Finally I receive array with 2 objects instead of 100. I need to get array with objects that processed in `getObject` function. 
If i code this:

```
dispatch_apply(inputArray.count, queue, ^(size_t index){

        [array insertObject:[self getObject:[inputArray objectAtIndex:index]] atIndex:index];

    });
```

I receive different numbers of array count. Can anybody tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: Based on your other questions (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724811/property-value-is-equal-null-objective-c) may I recommend you learn the basics a bit more before starting in this area as this is a bit more advanced stuff then what you seem to know already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `initWithCapacity` does **not** create an array with that many elements, it is just a hint to `NSMutableArray` on what the number of elements is likely to be. When you then try to insert an object at a specific instances things go wrong. From the docs for `insertObject:atIndex:`:

> Note that NSArray objects are not like C arrays. That is, even though you specify a size when you create an array, the specified size is regarded as a “hint”; the actual size of the array is still 0. This means that you cannot insert an object at an index greater than the current count of an array. For example, if an array contains two objects, its size is 2, so you can add objects at indices 0, 1, or 2. Index 3 is illegal and out of bounds; if you try to add an object at index 3 (when the size of the array is 2), NSMutableArray raises an exception.

You'll get different behaviour depending on the order the blocks queued by `dispatch_apply` are executed.

I'm assuming you are doing this as your `getObject:` is a time consuming process but multiple of them may be performed in parallel. If that is the case then:

a) After allocating the array pre-fill it up with cheap objects, e.g. `[NSNull null]` will do.

b) Use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` to add your objects to the array, this will replace your pre-filled object with your real ones.

**Note**: You are also misusing `__block`. This attribute is for when you wish to change the *value* of a local variable in the enclosing method from within a block. You **never** change the value of `array` either in the method or the block after you assign a *reference* to an `NSMutableArray` instance to it when it is declared. Your code then modifies the contents of the *referenced* object, not the *value* of the reference. Remove the `__block`.

HTH